# Calculate Market Share using MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database with every sale by store recorded.  I can query to get the total sales for each store:

```
Select SellerName, Count(*) as Sales From salesData Group By SellerName...
```

How do I create a query to show market share for each SellerName?

i.e.  sales count/total sales

Comment: Show table schema. Where do you have problems? Code seems ok, just add sum(total) , or sum(cost*quantity), I don't know table schema

Comment: Nope, that won't work because the aggregation will be limited to the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: I found a partial solution: SELECT SellerName, count(*) as YTD, concat(round(count(*)/
    (select count(*) from onlineData where BuyerZipCode = 90210)*100,1),'%') as '% of Total' FROM onlineData   WHERE BuyerZipCode = 90210 GROUP BY SellerName Order BY YTD DESC LIMIT 0, 700

Comment: @user1991642 see below

Comment: Glad that you found a partial solution. For you new questions, if you want to improve on your question or add clarifications, please just edit your question, instead of doing it via comments.

Comment: count(*) would give you the number of sales; SUM(some_col) will give you the total value of all sales ('some_col' is the amount of each sale entry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer with some improvements:

- No need to put the ZIP Code in SQL twice, just make it a condition between the inner & outer query. (See below)
- Surely hope you're storing `BuyerZipCode` as `VARCHAR`, not `INTEGER`.  So quote your ZIP, e.g.: `'90210'` not `90210`.
- Avoid number formatting in the SQL query (the multiply by 100, the rounding, the concat %) unless you have to. Whatever your front-end is (PHP, Excel, Crystal Reports) will do a fine job with formatting. *-- This one is a person preference and some will argue.*
- Indent for readability. *-- Again a personal thing; doesn't affect execution of the query, but helps debugging and encourages others to help you review your code.*

Code:

```
SELECT SellerName
      , count(*) ytd
      , count(*)/(SELECT count(*)
                  FROM onlineData
                  WHERE BuyerZipCode = o.BuyerZipCode) share
  FROM onlineData o
  WHERE BuyerZipCode = '90210'
  GROUP BY SellerName, BuyerZipCode
  Order BY ytd DESC
  LIMIT 0, 700 ;
```

**EDIT:**
Just revised the `GROUP BY SellerName` -> `GROUP BY SellerName, BuyerZipCode`.  It doesn't hurt or change the result when you are looking up one ZIP Code e.g. 90210, but if you want multiple zones `WHERE BuyerZipCode IN ('90210', '90211', '90212')` then it matters.  For market share calculation for every ZIP Code, simply cut out the `WHERE` clause out altogether.

Answer (score 0):

First you'd find out the gross sales

```
Select sum(salesAmount) as totalSalesAmount From salesData
```

Then you'd use that amount to calculate the percentage per salesperson

```
Select SellerName, sum(salesAmount)/totalSalesAmount as Sales From salesData Group By SellerName...
```

If you want it fancy, you could do in one query using the same table and projecting it with a different name

Comment: For this purpose - each record is a sale, dollar amount is not important, I want to be able to show Store X had 5.3% marketshare of sales volume in a given market.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SellerName, Count(*) as Sales, (Count(*)/(SELECT Count(*) FROM salesData))*100 as salesPerCent
From salesData Group By SellerName
```